# How to list all active and specific shortcodes in wordpress

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I wonder how you can list specific shortcodes, for example with this code you get a list of all active shortcode tags:

```
<?php 

global $shortcode_tags;

echo '<pre>'; print_r($shortcode_tags); echo '</pre>';

?>
```

I want to create a statement to get specific shortcodes tags for example:

we want a list of all shortcodes [hello]

```
if ($shortcode_tags==[hello]) {

echo '<pre>'; print_r($shortcode_tags[hello]); echo '</pre>';

}
```

Any suggest;
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional needs to test against strings which would be the name of the shortcode. If you're looking for the `[hello]` shortcode the conditional would look like:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $shortcode_tags['hello'] ); echo '</pre>';
```

So if you use [`add_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) the string you'll be looking for is the first parameter: `$tag`.