# How can I list only custom shortcodes?

Tags: shortcode

Wanting to list specific shortcodes I've added, rather than all shortcodes, can the code at [How to list all active and specific shortcodes in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167757/how-to-list-all-active-and-specific-shortcodes-in-wordpress) can be adapted to show only shortcodes which contain a specific word? (The custom shortcodes I want to access each contain the same specific word.)

And, if so, how...

I've searched extensively on this, and haven't found anything (nor know enough to decide if it's possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked question shows you how to get all the shortcode tags in an array. So narrowing them down to specific ones is purely a PHP question. But the answer's simple enough.

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on the array of tags with a callback function that uses [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to see if each tag contains the work you're looking for. Since the shortcode tag is the *key* in the array, use `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` to use the actual shortcode tag for the comparison in the callback function:

```
global $shortcode_tags;

$shortcodes = array_filter(
    $shortcode_tags,
    function( $shortcode_tag ) {
        return strpos( $shortcode_tag, 'woocommerce' ) !== false;
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```

In that example `$shortcodes` will now be all the shortcodes from `global $shortcode_tags;` that contain the word "woocommerce".

Comment: Thanks. I'm relatively inexperienced with PHP, so am currently reading about ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY to understand how I use it in this instance. So far, I have a feeling I'll have to return here and ask. ;-)

Comment: Clarifying my earlier comment... I see that 'it works as it is' - my uncertainty is with differences in echo/print/dump/other to output the array in a desired format. But that's another issue, beyond my immediate question.